# Deck of Cards Probabilty question

Tags: probability

So I have a problem that ask if a 4-card hands is dealt off of a standard 52-card deck. How many 4-card hands are there for which all 4 cards are of different suits or all 4 cards are red?

So far I have:

(13 1)^4= 28561 for the where the 4 card are of different suit

(26 4)= 14950 for the all red hand.

28561 + 14950= 43511 for (A ∪ B)-(A ∩ B)

I'm not sure if this is sufficuent or if there is more to answer.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to choose 4 cards from a standard deck of 52, where all 4 cards are among the same suit

There are 13C4 ways to choose 4 cards from any given suit. So the *total* number of ways in which 4 cards are red is 26C4 because there are *2* possible red suits. There are 14950 ways this could be done, just like you stated.

Then, the number of ways you could choose 4 cards of all different suits is just 13C1, which is just 13 ways to choose one card from each of the 4 suits.. $13^4$ = 28561, just like you stated.

The question poses "How many 4-card hands are there for which all 4 cards are of different suits $OR$ all 4 cards are red?"

With $OR$ statements we take the sum just like you did..

**You need to compute (A ∩ B)** and subtract this from (A ∪ B) which is just 43511

So yes, there is more to this question:

You need to solve for 43511-(A ∩ B)

The rule for $OR$ takes into account the values that may get counted more than once when the probability is determined.

Comment: Isn't $P(A \cap B)$ just 0? Also, we are not calculating probabilities here, rather we are just counting

Comment: Sounds right to me ;) I left that part for you, lol.

Comment: @nivekgnay and yeah youre right. I should have been a bit more specific in my usage of statistical terms. I changed it!